# How to echo a code inside foreach only once

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to echo a variable inside foreach only once
this the variable: $ads

this is the code:

```
    foreach ( $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['page'] as $page => $link ) {
        $host = $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['host'];
        $src  = $host . $link['src'];
        ?>
        <div class="page-break">
            <img id="image-<?php echo esc_attr( $page ); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>" class ="wp-manga-chapter-img">
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (unless `$ads` is dependant on data in the loop) to echo it before the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a counter like this :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['page'] as $page => $link ) {
    if($i==0) echo($ads);
    $i++;
    $host = $chapter['storage'][ $in_use ]['host'];
    $src  = $host . $link['src'];
    ?>
    <div class="page-break">
        <img id="image-<?php echo esc_attr( $page ); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>" class ="wp-manga-chapter-img">
    </div>
```